# API Call generates data as XML needing it to be JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, highcharts, quickbase

I am working with a database that uses QuickBase... What I am trying to accomplish is making a custom graph using HighCharts.

I had someone helping me do this earlier and they told me that I would need to make an API call from QuickBase to query the data I needed. I figured that out, but they went offline and now I am once again stuck scratching my head.

So far I have managed to set up my api call which looks like this
http://pastie.org/9351447

I was told that since it returns it as XML that it would not directly be able to populate a chart from there, so I am now trying to figure out how to turn this into what I am needing it to be (JS).

Comment: can you post actual exemples of what it is that you're "needing it to be" such as sample data, what it is (sample xml) and what you actually tried?

Comment: http://pastie.org/9351522#7     This is XML generated by the API call, As far as what I have tried, I haven't tried anything other than turning it into an HTML table using another API call, but from what I gather if I can get this into JSON it will be easier to work with and also more versatile to do more with the information it provides instead of just a graph

Answer (score 1):

So the API returns an xml data, and you need to use the xml data to Highcharts?
It seems Highcharts is capable of handling XML
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#2
So you should be able to populate your chart using the data provided by the API.

Comment: Okay, I somehow missed that when I was looking over the high charts information...I suppose they were telling me I needed it in JSON so I could easily use JS arrays to populate the chart, but I am sure I can figure out how to get it to work with my XML data with a bit of tinkering

Comment: Well I could understand how JSON would be easier to work with, especially when you are working in javascript where JSON is a more natural object for Javascript. You may want to consult this page for converting XML to JSON in javascript. http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/  Some API developers that I've worked with are able to return either JSON or XML, so perhaps talk to the API provider.